# Errors when using pip3 [socks.py line 199]

Tags: python, linux, pip, debian, python-3.6

I am running Kali Linux Debian [Rolling].
I changed my python2.7 to python3.6 from the path.
Then I installed pip by `apt-get install python3-pip` When I run pip/pip3 It gives me an error:

`pip or pip3`

```
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 646, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 616, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/contrib/socks.py", line 27, in <module>

  File "/usr/bin/socks.py", line 199
    raise Socks5AuthError,((3,_socks5autherrors[3]))
```

Comment: `python -v` is different than `python --version` (a.k.a `-V`); `-v` means *verbose*. Python isn't crashing there, it's just telling you what it is importing. Apart from that, can you include the *full* traceback you get?

Comment: If stack lets me...
https://pastebin.com/HqYtCUAc

Comment: I dont't want to remove my python 2.7 or 3. But... If I can remove all installed pythons on my Kali and reinstall again for fixing, it will be good